# Travis-ci doesn't quit after running bash script over ssh to start activator

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, travis-ci, typesafe-activator

We are trying to have travis continually deploy to our own server when our build is successful.

```
env:
  global:
    - ACTIVATOR_VERSION=1.3.7
    - ACTIVATOR_ZIP_FILE=typesafe-activator-${ACTIVATOR_VERSION}-minimal.zip
    - ACTIVATOR_ZIP_URL=http://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/${ACTIVATOR_VERSION}/${ACTIVATOR_ZIP_FILE}
    - ACTIVATOR_BIN=${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/activator-${ACTIVATOR_VERSION}-minimal/activator
    - "DEPLOY_USERNAME=#######"
    - "DEPLOY_PASSWORD=########"
    - "DEPLOY_HOST=########"

language: java

jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

addons:
  ssh_known_hosts:
    - ########
  apt:
    packages:
      - sshpass

install:
  - wget $ACTIVATOR_ZIP_URL
  - unzip -q $ACTIVATOR_ZIP_FILE

script:
  - $ACTIVATOR_BIN test

after_success:
  - sshpass -p $DEPLOY_PASSWORD ssh $DEPLOY_USERNAME@$DEPLOY_HOST -o stricthostkeychecking=no 'bash deploy.sh'
```

After our travis finishes without errors it runs an ssh script on our server to pull from our git, stop our running activator and start a new one.
**The script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
#Get the path of the local repository directory

set -o verbose

DIR="/home/ftpuser/eaglescience/"
TARGET="origin/develop"
SLEEP=1m

#echo "Go into directory " ${DIR}
cd ${DIR}
PID="`cat target/universal/stage/RUNNING_PID`"
#echo "Get the code from " ${TARGET}
git fetch --all
#echo "force checkout"
git checkout --force "${TARGET}"
#echo "Compiling activator"
activator clean stage
#echo "Running activator"
kill -15 ${PID}
target/universal/stage/bin/eaglescience -Dapplication.secret=############### &
#echo "Running..."
sleep ${SLEEP}
exit 0
```

The problem here is that Travis-ci does not exit the bash script after it runs (even with the exit 0). This means that Travis-CI will keep waiting for a response until it times out and erros our build

The response we got after a while is the following:

```
[success] Total time: 33 s, completed Mar 9, 2016 11:19:20 AM
#echo "Running activator"
kill -15 ${PID}
target/universal/stage/bin/eaglescience -Dapplication.secret=########### &
#echo "Running..."
sleep ${SLEEP}
[warn] - application - system properties: application.secret is deprecated, use play.crypto.secret instead
[info] - play.api.Play - Application started (Prod)
[info] - play.core.server.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
exit 0
No output has been received in the last 10 minutes, this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.
The build has been terminated
```

We have tried a lot of different things, we have tried to run the ssh bash command silent. But then travis-ci terminates the connection almost instantly and the command wil not run. We also tried to add `&& exit 0` but then the server still keeps waiting on response.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `nohup` the shell file with output to `/dev/null 2>&1 &` eg : `nohup filename.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

Comment: Hallo Jespert,Thank you for your answer, unfortunately i cannot check your answer because this was a project I did a while a go and i have solved it on a other way. But thank you for the answer!

Comment: To be honest i don't know anymore, it is a while back when i have done this project sorry.